# How to change the language in the VS-Code terminal window?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

My computer is running in the german language.
My VS-Code language was set with "Configure Display Language" in the settings (press F1) to English. But the terminal window displays message still in German.
What can I do?

Edit: 
I think I have to change my PowerShell language.

Comment: What messages specifically? I can't really reproduce it because the only text from VSCode I get is "Terminal", which is the same in both English and my locale, and the rest come from Windows itself.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález For example when I get an error message it is displayed in German.

Comment: Don't those messages come from whatever command or program you are running in the terminal? I think you have high expectancies on what [Display Language](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales) can do. It just controls the strings in the program itself, not the rest of the computer.

Comment: I changed my system language to English now. And of course this is working.